# Añadir etiqueta inspinia

Tags: soporte, etiquetas

Hace poco pregunté una duda sobre la plantilla `INSPINIA` la cual es una modificación de `bootstrap`, y cuando fui a poner las etiquetas, noté en falta la etiqueta.

Aunque no haya muchas preguntas sobre esa plantilla, ¿no sería recomendable tenerla como etiqueta?

Comment: En realidad tu pregunta es la primera que habla sobre esa plantilla.

Comment: @ArtEze supongo, aunque ha recibido votos positivos desde que creé la etiqueta, supongo que ahora habrá más preguntas

Comment: @AlbertoMartínez No, mira [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=inspinia+is%3Aquestion).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cualquier usuario con 300 o más de reputación puede [crear nuevas etiquetas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags).

Te recomendaría editar tu pregunta original para agregarle la etiqueta. Con eso estará disponible para cualquier usuario.

Es importante ser muy responsable a la hora de crear nuevas etiquetas, y estar completamente seguro de no estar generando una meta-etiqueta. Pero en casos como este, lo veo totalmente válido.

Más información en: [¿Qué son las etiquetas, y cómo debo usarlas?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Mariano, simplemente preguntaba por si alguien veia una meta-etiqueta o que no era necesaria, pero si el válida a ello voy!

Comment: Aunque pasado cierto tiempo se borra la etiqueta si no hay más publicaciones que la usan, no ?

Comment: 6 meses sin otra pregunta

Comment: @lois6b : Y si no tiene otra etiqueta se le asigna [tag:untagged]